# Building different templates based on data type in javascript module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am passing data to a javascript file to build HTML based on the data type of the object. I am then exporting the module to the other javascript file to generate an HTML file with that module's HTML widget.

Below is the code I am working with. I am sure I am missing something simple, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am also interested in advice on how to optimize what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

```
function createWidget(data) {
    switch(data.type) {
        case "logo":
            console.log(data.type);
            createLogoWidget(data);
            break;
        case "contact":
            console.log(data.type);
            createContactWidget(data);
            break;
        case "links":
            console.log(data.type);
            createLinksWidget(data);
            break;
        default:
    }
}
createLogoWidget = (data) => `
    <div>createLogoWidget</div>
    <div>${data.type}</div>
`;
createContactWidget = (data) => `
    <div>createContactWidget</div>
    <div>${data.type}</div>
`;
createLinksWidget = (data) => `
    <div>createLinksWidget</div>
    <div>${data.type}</div>
`;
module.exports = createWidget;
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I altered you code a little . The juice of the example lies in the call to the logo option of the switch ...

I take it that you were looking for a method to create HTML on the fly in Node.JS

Even though you called the backtick operator

> ``

Ive never seen HTML code in js just generate itself without using an `div.innerHTML = '...'` 
So in this example I create the element with JS and pass the params as variables .

Another thing I noted was you were using the parameter `data.type`

unless you using a structured JSON string that wont work with a single variable

e.g`var data ={type : 'logo',value :"this is the logo" }`

Also calling `${data.type}` might be that you would be using jquery,react or vue.js In My example is just plain JS and it works well without the 3rd party overheads for node JS.

for easy explanation I just used a single variable's in the example to give you an easy way just to grasp the method.You could go as far as adding classes and events to your dynamic html elements and generate an entire interface out of it

So within your logo switch all the code to do that is there

```js
function createWidget(data,targetDiv,dataContents) {
switch(data) {
case "logo":
    console.log(data);
    createLogoWidget(data,targetDiv,dataContents);
    break;
case "contact":
    console.log(data);
    createContactWidget(data);
    break;
case "links":
    console.log(data);
    createLinksWidget(data);
    break;
default:
}
}
createLogoWidget = (data,targetDiv,dataContents) =>{

        let div1 = document.createElement('div');
        div1.innerHTML = 'create Logo Widget'
        
        
        let target = document.getElementById(targetDiv);
        target.appendChild(div1);


        let div2 = document.createElement('h2');
        div2.classList.add("header");
        div2.innerHTML = dataContents;
        div2.addEventListener('click',function(e){console.log('header Click')})
        target.appendChild(div2);


        //`
        //<div>createLogoWidget</div>
        //<div></div>
        //`;

}

createContactWidget = (data) => `
<div>createContactWidget</div>
<div></div>
`;
createLinksWidget = (data) => `
<div>createLinksWidget</div>
<div></div>
`;

//call the function

createWidget('logo','demo','MY Heading');
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

You can edit the other types on your own but it should give you a basic idea of what you were missing

Another thing that you should look into when building modules for nodeJS is to use the UMD or Universal Model Definition

This means that you code will work both in NODEJS , WEB and AMD stands for Asynchronous Module Definition.

You can copy your modules anywhere and out the box without having to edit them use

- `require('yourModule');`
- `import 'yourModule';`
- or `<script src="yourmodule.js"></script>`

It just works everywhere if you have done that . Here is a link to help you get to grips with the UMD methodology 
[UMD ASM CJS](https://dev.to/iggredible/what-the-heck-are-cjs-amd-umd-and-esm-ikm)